# How to read a video embedded in a ᴘᴅꜰ?

Tags: video, pdf

A simple question on a ᴘᴄ.
But on Android, even the official reader doesn’t allows it.

This is for reading the video inside/with the ᴘᴅꜰ, not extracting it.

Comment: Unfortunately, stack exchange doesn’t allows to share an exemple because of the format.

Comment: You can use a file hosting service, or even Google Drive to share that PDF with us to test.

Comment: Please [edit] to mention Android Version and device details and what is the *official reader*?

Comment: @beeshyams the reader devlopped by the designer of the pdf format which is Adobe.